# Record video using AVFoundation that is cropped to the VideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the AVFoundation framework and implementing according to  to capture video and setting up a previewLayer on my view that shows an output size of 640 x 480.  I would like to have the video cropped to this frame (so the user gets exactly what they see in the UI as an output) but I am having trouble finding the point at which such a change should take place.

I would like to crop the video before / during capture rather than after the user takes the video as the user will be shooting multiple videos in a "wizard" and I am trying to limit time between steps.

Is this even possible?

here is the setup code for the capture session:

```
AVCaptureSession *newCaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
newCaptureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame1280x720;


// Add inputs and output to the capture session
if ([newCaptureSession canAddInput:newVideoInput]) {
    [newCaptureSession addInput:newVideoInput];
}
if ([newCaptureSession canAddInput:newAudioInput]) {
    [newCaptureSession addInput:newAudioInput];
}
if ([newCaptureSession canAddOutput:newStillImageOutput]) {
    [newCaptureSession addOutput:newStillImageOutput];
}

[self setStillImageOutput:newStillImageOutput];
[self setVideoInput:newVideoInput];
[self setAudioInput:newAudioInput];
[self setSession:newCaptureSession];


// Set up the movie file output
NSURL *outputFileURL = [self tempFileURL];
AVCamRecorder *newRecorder = [[AVCamRecorder alloc] initWithSession:[self session] outputFileURL:outputFileURL];
[newRecorder setDelegate:self];

// Send an error to the delegate if video recording is unavailable
if (![newRecorder recordsVideo] && [newRecorder recordsAudio]) {
    NSString *localizedDescription = NSLocalizedString(@"Video recording unavailable", @"Video recording unavailable description");
    NSString *localizedFailureReason = NSLocalizedString(@"Movies recorded on this device will only contain audio. They will be accessible through iTunes file sharing.", @"Video recording unavailable failure reason");
    NSDictionary *errorDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               localizedDescription, NSLocalizedDescriptionKey, 
                               localizedFailureReason, NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey, 
                               nil];
    NSError *noVideoError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"AVCam" code:0 userInfo:errorDict];
    if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManager:didFailWithError:)]) {
        [[self delegate] captureManager:self didFailWithError:noVideoError];
    }
}

[self setRecorder:newRecorder];
```

The video record start method:

```
-(void)startRecordingWithOrientation:(AVCaptureVideoOrientation)videoOrientation;
{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = [AVCamUtilities     connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo fromConnections:[[self movieFileOutput] connections]];

if ([videoConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
    [videoConnection setVideoOrientation:videoOrientation];

[[self movieFileOutput] startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[self outputFileURL] recordingDelegate:self];
}
```